# Symfony VichUploaderBundle rename file

Tags: symfony, filenames, vichuploaderbundle

Hi is there a way to rename uploaded file using VichUploaderBundle? If I upload two image with same name it will remove the old one and it's a problem for me.

I have configuration exactly the same like in the [doc](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md)

Comment: You'll probably need to implement a [custom file namer](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/file_namer/howto/create_a_custom_file_namer.md).

Comment: check the `File Namer` component [here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/namers.md). I usually use the standard namer_uniqid as described in the doc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this kind of issues, the bundle provide "[file namers](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/namers.md)". They are simple services used to name files, in particular to avoid collisions on the filesystem.

You probably want to use the `vich_uploader.namer_origname` file namer as it will rename your uploaded files using a uniqueid as the prefix of the filename and keeping the original name and extension (a file named `foo.jpg` will be stored as `50eb3db039715_foo.jpg`)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, please check the url of the link, I think it has changed to:https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/namers.md

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `namer` in your `vich_uploader.yaml`

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        product_image:
                  namer: vich_uploader.namer_origname
```